# Add to dictionary some params from request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get some params from `Request`

I need from Request.Params all params with text contains "txt" I have more type of text structure:

```
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtPhone"
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtPhone2"
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtPhone3"
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtAdr1"
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtAdr2"
"ctl00$cphMain$repDelTypes$ctl00$ucDel$txtAdr3"
```

how Get value all text after "txt"

```
var dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, string>();

 foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
 { 
      if (key.ToString().Contains("txt"))
                {
                 // add to dictionary name and value
                // dictionary.Add("name", "val");
                }
 }
```

Comment: Imho this is not a good aproach since your dictionary relies on control-id's. This could lead to nasty errors in future if you or your colleagues have forgotten that it matters.

Comment: This approach is very prone to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to add to the dictionary?

```
var dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
{ 
     if (key.ToString().Contains("txt"))
     {
          //get the text after "txt"
          var index = Request.Params[key].LastIndexOf("txt");
          var val = Request.Params[key].SubString(index);
          Dictionary.Add(key, val);
     }
}
```

Comment: I need text after "txt" add to dictionary and value

Comment: Error cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]' on position Split("txt")[1];

Comment: oh right i forgot split takes a char. The other answers provide better ways to get the text after "txt"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
{ 
     if (key.ToString().Contains("txt"))
     {
          int index = Request.Params[key].LastIndexOf("txt");
          Dictionary.Add(key, Request.Params[key].SubString(index));
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, string>();

 foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
 { 
      if (key.ToString().Contains("txt"))
      {
         // add to dictionary name and value
         dictionary.Add(key.Split(new string[]{"txt"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1], Request.Params[key]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]' on position Split("txt")[1];

Comment: Error 59 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'char[]'

Comment: Ok, needs the split options parameter, see edits above.